# How to Place ng-5 range sliders labels into range slider pointers in angular?

Tags: css, angular

i have customized range slider width and height but the label Legend can't be edited.I have to place the label text to inside my range pointer

html:

```
<ng5-slider [(value)]="valueOne" [options]="ValueOpt"></ng5-slider>
```

typescript:

```
valueOne = 0; 
ValueOpt: Options = { 
   vertical: true,
   showSelectionBar: false,
   showTicksValues: false,
   disabled: true,
   stepsArray: [ 
     { value: 0, legend: 'Off' },
     { value: 20, legend: 'Very low' },
     { value: 40, legend: 'Low' },
     { value: 60, legend: 'Neutral' },
     { value: 80, legend: 'high' },
     { value: 100, legend: 'Very high' }
   ]
   hideLimitLabels: true,
   translate: (valueOne: number, label: LabelType): string => { 
     console.log();
     switch (valueOne) {
       case 0:
         return '<b>Off</b>';
       case 20:
         return '<b>Very low</b>';
       case 40: 
         return '<b>Low</b>';
       case 60: 
         return '<b>Netural</b>';
       case 80: 
         return '<b>High</b>'; 
       case 100:
         return '<b>Very high</b>';
       default: return ' ';
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: can you give some sample code please ?

Comment: <ng5-slider [(value)]="valueOne" [options]="ValueOpt"></ng5-slider>

Comment: valueOne = 0;
  ValueOpt: Options = {
    vertical: true,
    showSelectionBar: false,
    showTicksValues: false,
    disabled: true,
    stepsArray: [
      { value: 0, legend: 'Off' },
      { value: 20, legend: 'Very low' },
      { value: 40, legend: 'Low' },
      { value: 60, legend: 'Neutral' },
      { value: 80, legend: 'high' },
      { value: 100, legend: 'Very high' },
    ],

Comment: hideLimitLabels: true,
    translate: (valueOne: number, label: LabelType): string => {
      console.log();
      switch (valueOne) {
        case 0:
          return '<b>Off</b>';
        case 20:
          return '<b>Very low</b>';
        case 40:
          return '<b>Low</b>';
        case 60:
          return '<b>Netural</b>';
        case 80:
          return '<b>High</b>';
        case 100:
          return '<b>Very high</b>';
        default:

          return ' ';
      }
    }
  };

Comment: By using ng-deep i have changed some properties but unable to move the labels inside the pointer